# Nonlinear geometric control for beginners

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, control-theory, nonlinear-system, adaptive-control

Please advise literature or articles on nonlinear geometric control (for beginners). Preferably with computational examples. I want to study this topic, but I do not know where to start.

**Remark:**

Thanks to everyone who advised the book. I have not studied all the questions, but the initial presentation in my head has taken shape. Some of the "white spots" in these books for me remain: 1. Computational aspects. The object is represented in a similar way to the classical form in the state space as А * x + B * u, which is easy to model in Simulink. How are computations organized in the framework of group theory? 2. Optimum. How is a system created in the framework of geometrical control, the transient processes in which are characterized by given parameters: overshoot and the end time of the transition process? 3. Control of non-linear objects with features: are there any advantages of geometric control of non-linear objects, for example, with friction?

I hope my questions are relevant and correctly posed.

Comment: In my opinion, Isidori's "Nonlinear Control Systems" is a must-read if you want to dive into geometric nonlinear control.

Comment: Are you talking about the book "Nonlinear Control Systems: an Introduction"? 303 p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Geometric Optimal Control by  Schättler-Ledzewicz](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461438335). They do a lot of applications. I also liked Sussman's [Introduction to the coordinate-free Maximum Principle](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.31.5780) for a more philosophical take. There is also one by Russian authors, [Control Theory from Geometric Viewpoint by Agrachev-Sachkov](http://www.botik.ru/PSI/CPRC/sachkov/notes.pdf), but I am not sure about "for beginners". A very different type of geometric approach, based not on Pontryagin's maximum principle but rather geometric feedback approach,  is in [Singular Optimal Control in Mathematical Economics by Zelikin-Borisov](http://science.org.ge/cma/v11.pdf). They are pretty elementary and do many examples.

Comment: There are so many books now released ... just a monstrous amount of information, and finding something worthwhile in it is not an easy task.
Thank you for the selection that you have advised. I will study it.
Yesterday I came across a book by F. Bullo and A. Lewis, "Geometric Control of Mechanical Systems." For a beginner, it seemed to me difficult, however, the material itself is applicable specifically to control systems, so it needs to be studied first.